# Sum of the a column in each pages

Tags: javascript, php, yii, javascript-objects, dom-events

[image: here is the table]

I want to print the sum of Amount column of each page by using column name of database which is "amount_no" and "Amount" in a table. It means named as, in front end "Amount" and back end "amount_no". Now I want to use one of these names to print the sum of column instead of column number(4) I used in my coding.
Help me please as I'm a beginner in PHP.

```
<script type="text/javascript" class="init">


$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
        var api = this.api(), data;

        // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
        var intVal = function ( i ) {
            return typeof i === 'string' ?
                i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                typeof i === 'number' ?
                    i : 0;
        };

        // Total over all pages
        total = api
            .column( 4 )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Total over this page
        pageTotal = api
            .column( 4, { page: 'current'} )
            .data()
            .reduce( function (a, b) {
                return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
            }, 0 );

        // Update footer
        $( api.column( 4 ).footer() ).html(
            'Rs '+ pageTotal +' ( Rs '+ total +' total)'
        );
    }
  } );
} );


 </script>
```

PHP:

```
 <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="5" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
 <tbody style="font-size:12px;">
<?php   
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($find))
     {
    $id = $row['id'];
        $receipt_no = $row['receipt_no'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $on_account = $row['on_account'];
        $deceased_name = $row['deceased_name'];
        $subDate = $row['subDate'];
        $others = $row['others'];
    $amount_no = $row['amount_no'];
        $amount_word = $row['amount_word'];
    $currency = $row['currency'];
    $payment = $row['payment'];
    $cheque_draft_no = $row['cheque_draft_no'];
    $total_amount += $amount_no;


    echo '<tr>';
        foreach($_POST['field'] as &$field_value) {
            switch ($field_value) {
                case '1':
                    echo '<td><input name="selector[]" class="checkbox1"          id="edit-delete" type="checkbox" value="' . $id . '"></td>';
                    break;
                case '2':
                    echo '<td>' . $receipt_no . '</td>';
                    break;
                case '3':
                    echo '<td>' . $name . '</td>';
                    break;
                case '4':
                   echo '<td>' . $on_account. '</td>';
                    break;
                case '5':
                    echo '<td>' . $deceased_name. '</td>';
                    break;
                case '6':
                    echo '<td>' . $subDate. '</td>';
                    break;
                case '7':
                    echo '<td>' . $others. '</td>';
                    break;
                case '8':

                    echo '<td>' . $amount_no. '</td>';
                    break;
                case '9':
                    echo '<td>' . $amount_word. '</td>';
                    break;
                case '10':
                    echo '<td>' . $currency. '</td>';
                    break;
                case '11':
                    echo '<td>' . $payment. '</td>';
                    break;
                case '12':
                    echo '<td>' . $cheque_draft_no. '</td>';
                    break;


            }
        }


    ?>
    <?php echo '</tr>';

}

?>
```

Comment: There is no PHP here, this is all javascript.

Comment: @chris85 here is code.<tfoot>
    <tr>
    <th colspan="5" style="text-align:right">Total:</th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
     </tfoot>

Comment: That's `HTML`.. Use the `edit` link under the `tags` to add more code.

Comment: @chris85 check it out please..

Answer (score -1):

Its a bit hard to understand actually what you mean, maybe try to explain somehow different separating code etc.

But as far as I understood you have a database and you want to sum all of data from your column, why not doing that in SQL?

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

Comment: Actullay im trying to do the sum of the Amount column in each pages and total sum too. and its  calculating correctly  with the above code. Now i want to calculate it with the column name instead of column number. i,e 4. in my case. Hope u got my problem this time. thanks a lot.

Comment: So you mean that you want the $field_value from the switch to not be a number and you want it a string?